# Connect php webapplication with tally prime to exchange data

Tags: php, tally

I am new to tally(https://tallysolutions.com/tally-prime/) I want to send my sales data from my php web application to tally prime and vice-versa. But its documentation is so confusing can anyone guide me ?
Do we need to use TDL to connect php web application with tally prime to send data. Or we can do this without TDL also. I am taking reference from here https://help.tallysolutions.com/article/DeveloperReference/

Answer (score 0):

- If you have knowledge in TDL you can link your web application using
  API in JSON/XML format. - Complex
- If you don't known TDL you can generate Tally complaint xml in your
  web application ask end user to upload it in tally - Easy to develop
  but hard for end users as they need to manually upload xmls and
  doesn't known if error occurs
- Easier way is create a desktop app that runs along with tally and
  connect tally with your web application using both applications API -
  Medium, End user need to setup once

So, You can integrate php web application with tally prime with or without TDL